# Calling property object from within class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, properties

I am trying to call a property from within its class and get the value. I understand that properties are `A.foo.__get__(a)`, but since the properties are within the instance of the class I am not sure what my `a` would be. Currently, my attempts return the object and location. This makes sense, but how would I proceed so that it instead returns the value of the property?

```
class Burgers(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.burger1 = self.make_burger_dict('mc')
        self.burger2 = self.make_burger_dict('bk')
        print self.burger1
        # prints {1: <property object at 0x10d51b7e0>, 2: <property object at 0x10d51b7e0>}
        # what I want {1: 'Big Mac', 2: 'Big Mac'}


    @property
    def bk(self):
        return "Whopper"

    @property
    def mc(self):
        return "Big Mac"

    def make_burger_dict(self, key):
        return {
            1: vars(Burgers)[key],
            2: getattr(Burgers, key),
        }

x = Burgers()
```

I tried `3: eval("self." + key)` in the make_burger_dict method, and that creates the desired outcome. However, I've heard to avoid `eval`, so is there away to do this without using it?

Comment: you tried `getattr(Burgers, key)` but not `getattr(self, key)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  You shouldn't have to deal with the `__get__` nonsense.  That's the whole point of creating a descriptor on a class; python handles it automagically.

```
def make_burger_dict(self, key):
    val = getattr(self, key)
    return {1: val, 2: val}
```